# Setting Clicking Priority for a div with an href

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, click, onclicklistener

I am very new to javascript, I am trying to use `.glyphicon-remove` to close a bookmark I created. However that bookmark floater has a `href` link and every time I click on `.glyphicon-remove` the floater disappears and I am redirected to the `href` link. I only want to be able to be directed to the link if the click event isn't on the `.glyphicon-remove`. When the `.glyphicon-remove` is clicked I just want the bookmark to disappear and not redirect me to its relevant link. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to accomplish this functionality?

```
function removeBookmark(event){

  if (!event.target.matches('.glyphicon-remove')) return;

  // find index of clicked item
  // looks inside parent of span i.e. the bookmark class for its data id
  const index = event.target.parentNode.dataset.id;

  // remove from bookmarks
  bookmarks.splice(index, 1);
  // fill the new list
  fillBookMarksList(bookmarks);
  // store new list back to local storage
  storeBookmarks(bookmarks);

}
```

and this is a snippet of the href

```
<a href="${newBookMark.link}" class="bookmark" data-id="${i}">
```

and here is a relevant part of the HTML

```
bookmark .glyphicon-remove {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  color: #EEE;
  transition: 0.3s ease color;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: You need to manipulate the bubbling of the click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if the class name check you're using works - I'd do it this way instead:

```
 if (!event.target.classList.contains('glyphicon-remove')) 
   return;

 //prevent default click behaviour
 event.preventDefault();
 event.returnValue = false;

 // find index of clicked item
 // looks inside parent of span i.e. the bookmark class for its data id
 const index = event.target.parentNode.dataset.id;

 // remove from bookmarks
 bookmarks.splice(index, 1);
 // fill the new list
 fillBookMarksList(bookmarks);
 // store new list back to local storage
 storeBookmarks(bookmarks);
```

the `event.preventDefault()` function should prevent the regular click behaviour (provided the event target has the

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `event.preventDefault()` method to not trigger link default onclick event.
More information can be found here
[preventDefault()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_preventdefault.asp)